# Secure cookies aren't set when navigating in iframe

Tags: security, cookies, yii2, cross-domain

I have an application where a container app loads site `<inner-site>.com` in an iframe. All the ajax calls in the iframe fails due to bad request. This was due to ajax calls not having `_csrf` cookie in the request. For some reason, iframe doesn't have the identity cookies at-all.

Problem mentioned here: https://gist.github.com/iansltx/18caf551baaa60b79206 and the proposed solution was to remove the same-site requirement for identity cookies. That didn't sound like a good plan.

Then, I found more elegant way to share cookies between sites here: https://gist.github.com/iansltx/18caf551baaa60b79206
I liked the solution since the client and server work together and I could limit who to trust from `<inner-site>`.
This solution also worked on localhost which was awesome since we have been trying to fix this issue for weeks by now.

However, after deploying the change to the prod, it no longer worked. Not sure what might be causing this issue or if the limitations were more relaxed in localhost that it worked fine.

I'm looking for help figuring out either

- why the solution above didn't work for the real server
- or if there's another solution for this problem.

I'm using Yii2 but any solution should be applicable. Mentioned Yii2 to see if it might be enforcing some extra limitation or if it has some utility to fix this issue easier.